# Usefulness of Differential Geometry

Tags: computational-geometry, mathematical-programming, mathematical-foundations, mathematical-software

I recently came across these books:

- [Differential Geometry and Lie Groups: A Computational Perspective](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783030460396#aboutBook)
- [Differential Geometry and Lie Groups: A Second Course](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030460464#aboutBook)

Their subject matter really intrigues me, as I really enjoy topology/geometry/analysis, but had not planned to pursue them since I also want to work in an area with very concrete application. However, I am skeptical. At one point I thought topological data analysis (TDA) was the perfect marriage of my interests, but I have found very little evidence of that field actually being used in computer science, much less in industrial or otherwise more 'practical' settings. It seems like TDA makes mathematicians feel more relevant to the data science world, but I'm not convinced that it makes them so (feel free to contradict me if you think I'm wrong on this point, but note that I want a concrete use case, not an abstract argument about its relevance). I have similar stories about coding theory, certain aspects of set theory, etcetera. They may have theoretical relevance, but is there any situation where, in the process of developing software, one might need to consult theses fields? I don't know of any.

So now my question: is there any practical field of computer science that makes advanced use of differential geometry? Medical imaging, other imaging, computer graphics, virtual reality, and some other fields come to mind as potential application areas. In my (admittedly limited) experience, however, these areas seem to use basic 3D geometry, numerical linear algebra, and sometimes numerical analysis of PDEs. Those are all very nice topics, but they do not require anything as abstract as differential geometry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/DDG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mainly see differential geometry applied to computer science in the following applied subfields:

- Computer Graphics / Geometry processing
- Machine Learning / Signal Processing

For Computer Graphics / Geometry processing, recommend looking for:

- [Discrete Differential geometry course by Keenan Crane](https://brickisland.net/DDGSpring2020/)
- [Discrete Differential geometry for CS playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_bUBfdffRU&list=PLQ3UicqQtfNvPmZftPyQ-qK1wdXBxj86W)
- [Compilation of Discrete Differential geometry papers](http://www.geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/GSD06.pdf)

For Machine Learning /Signal Processing recommend looking for:

- Manifold Learning
- Information Geometry
- Nonlinear Signal processing
- [Geometric Deep Learning](http://geometricdeeplearning.com/)

Also check this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350228/how-useful-is-differential-geometry-and-topology-to-deep-learning) in Math exchange, and this conference [Differential Geometry meets Deep Learning](https://nips.cc/Conferences/2020/ScheduleMultitrack?event=16116)

Btw the [Functional Differential Geometry](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7884551) is a great book.

Comment: This is really helpful - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you found *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* interesting, you might like [Functional Differential Geometry](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/functional-differential-geometry) (It's from the same authors) .

> Differential geometry is deceptively simple. It is surprisingly easy to get the right answer with unclear and informal symbol manipulation.  To address this problem we use computer programs to communicate a precise understanding of the computations in differential geometry.  Expressing the methods of differential geometry in a computer language forces them to be unambiguous and computationally effective. The task of formulating a method as a computer-executable program and debugging that program is a powerful exercise in the learning process.  Also, once formalized procedurally, a mathematical idea becomes a tool that can be used directly to compute results.

Taken from [Sussman, Wisdom: *Functional Differential Geometry*](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/wisdom/AIM-2005-003.pdf)

Comment: This seems to be more teaching differential geometry by making use of computer science than the other way around.

Comment: I agree with Discrete lizard, this doesn’t seem to be relevant to the original question. But it looks interesting nonetheless!

Comment: Yeah, I just happen to stumble upon it a while back. Maybe I should add a disclaimer :)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, every field which has the name "differential" in it, is somehow applied in neural networks.
For differential geometry for example you can think about differential rendering in computer graphics.

At the moment I am working with the paper "A Differential Theory of Radiative Transfer" by Zhang et al.

Comment: Thanks, but do you happen to have a specific example? Differential equations (the other most prominent field that I know with differential in it) can be studied at a very “applied” level, which is quite different from studying differential geometry (at least from what I’ve seen).

Comment: That's not really what differential geometry is.